# Collections does not exist in my mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I created some collections (tables) in "mongodb" when I restart the server or laptop, the collections which I created does not appear. I can see only admin and local databases when I type "show dbs".
My mongo version is, v4.0.6

Comment: I have already added / inserted many records to the collections before restaring the laptop. Even added records collections do not appear.

Comment: Can you try again and give examples of you starting, writing, reading, and restarting. There are tons of reasons why your data may be missing.

Comment: thank you, i wil try and let you know. I am new to this database since i have been using mysql , mssql since 2006.

Answer (score 0):

Insert atleast one data to the collection. Collection will appear.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond. I have already added more records.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the collection,you have to insert the document/data as well .
If you won't insert any data into the collection,it won't be existing in the database.
Try 
db..insert({,})

Comment: Hi siva, thank you for answering. The issue is i have already inserted many records to my collections.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have added the collection into a wrong database. **If you used mongodb shell, then maybe you forgot to use `use <database>` shell command and so your collection might be added into a wrong database.** Try to switch between all the databases using `use <database>` and look for the collection using `show collections` shell command. Maybe this will help you, sir.

Comment: first I created database called "ijse" after creating ijse database, I moved to the db using "use ijse" after that I create collections and all. Your point is also correct.